# FileZilla client run in command line

Tags: ftp, filezilla

is it possible to run FileZilla client via command line and be able to set server name, user, password, FTP protocol (e.g. FTPES, SFTP), port number?  i looked online and can't seem to be able to find any such command.  also, i am using windows 7, i am not sure if that somehow has a smaller set of commands.  thanks.

Comment: so you want to automate which process? login?

Comment: Create a site first in GUI then specify the site through "--site" in the command line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [some command-line arguments for FileZilla](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client)), but as far as i know, it's principally a GUI FTP client.

Otherwise, Windows have a bundled command line FTP client (FTP.exe)

- [The Windows Command-Line FTP Client](http://www.textheavy.com/tutorials/winftp.html)
- [List of FTP commands for the Microsoft command-line FTP client](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm)

Comment: This is the right answer, but the Windows FTP client sucks so bad it doesn't support Passive mode.  So if you're behind a firewall, or if the server is, chances you wont be able to get/put files.  Communications will probably work though since FTP uses a different channel for that.  So you can connect and change directories, but not get/put files.  Awesome.

Comment: I'm currently modifying FileZilla (it is opensource after all) to be more commandline friendly. e.g. connect to server, set local and remote paths, and queue files for upload. When I'm finished I submit a patch back the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ncftpput`. `ncftpput` supports command-line file upload and it has other commands.

ex: `ncftpget`, `ncftpls`, and support auto create file folder.